# Upload same file multiple times without choosing it second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a web page which offers file upload and returns a report.
Is it possible to change the file in the background and then re-upload the same file using AJAX without choosing it in the upload form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The user would have to re-select and re-upload the file.

That said, the idea doesn't really make sense to me.

Why not simply keep the uploaded file on server side, assign it a unique ID, and pass that around in your forms? Should the uploaded file be needed again, you can retrieve it using that ID without having to re-upload it.

Comment: Point is that user should change the file on the local computer and easily resend it for processing.

Comment: @Marko You will not be able to do that without the user choosing the file again - at least not using standard HTML / jQuery / Ajax. Maybe using the HTML 5 Upload API or Flash though, I don't know